# Error occured: MongoError: driver is incompatible with this server version

Tags: mongoose, node-mongodb-native

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    LocationModel = mongoose.model('location')

exports.createLocation = function(req, res, next) {
  var locationModel = new LocationModel(req.body);
   locationModel.save(function(err, article) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(200);
            res.json({
                type: false,
                data: "Error occured: " + err
            })
        } else {
            res.json({
                type: true,
                data: article
            })
        }
    })
}
```

While trying to save using model file i am getting driver is incompatible with this server version.

Comment: This would seem to indicate a very old MongoDB. Which version are you connecting to?

Comment: What version of Mongoose, MongoDB server, and the node MongoDB driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of mongoose & update to the dependencies in package.json.

Latest version of mongoose is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose).

At npm repository of package the dependencies of mongodb is described.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that your local meteor project version is not compact to the meteor version on server.

1) Update your server meteor to latest.(is meteor.com? go step 2.)

2) Enter your local meteor project, type

```
meteor update --patch
```

Now you can deploy your app to server again.